# Ejecutar metodo de componente Vue al seleccionar un option de un select

Tags: vue.js

De que forma podria hacer que se ejecute un metodo en Vue Js al seleccionar una opcion de un select? En mi aplicacion el usuario selecciona un mes de la lista y entonces quiero que se haga una consulta a la BD por medio de axios en tiempo real, sin que el usuario tengra que presionar un boton "buscar" por ejemplo, para que se ejecute mi metodo Vue js de mi componente? Estoy trabajando con PHP. Ya logre que al presionar el boton se haga la peticion con axios pero quiero que se haga asincrono sin tener que presionar un boton.

Comment: Asincronico, no tiene nada que ver con presionar o no un boton. En realidad vos lo queres automatico al seleccionar una opcion.. y esta llamada seguro se hace asincronicamente al servidor ;) mas alla de eso, si mostras tu codigo podemos ayudarte para ver donde esta el problema.

Answer (score 3):

Buenas noches Eduardo.

veo que lo tienes todo realizado pero pulsando el boton buscar, el select puede emiter eventos al cambiar entre sus ítem con "@change="metodoAejecutar()", si defines un v-model al select puedes capturar el value de los options del select te paso un ejemplo.

```
<div id="app">
 <select name="LeaveType" @change="onchange()" class="form-control" v-model="key">
  <option value="1">Annual Leave/ Off-Day</option>
  <option value="2">On Demand Leave</option>
 </select>
</div>


new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  key: "",
 },
 methods: {
 onchange: function() {
   console.log(this.key)
   alert(this.key)
  }
 }
})

introducir el código aquí
```

[Ejemplo Vue Select](https://jsfiddle.net/13qpbzcn/3/)

Comment: bienvenido, el ejemplo va aquí, por que si ese enlace deja de funcionar entonces la respuesta pierde sentido

Comment: El ejemplo esta perfecto.. si copias el mismo en la respuesta, para que futuros usuarios lo puedan ver, seguro vas a quitar esos negativos y tu respuesta podria ser aceptada.

Comment: listo, muchas gracias a los dos, en especial a  @gbianchi